# can i limit number of onScrolled() method call per touch event in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

How to be limit number of times call and runs method OnScrolled() in RecyclerView ?? Because there are a number of conditions in it, very much executing this code,Cause slowdown the application.

condition :

```
if (dy < 0 && mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() >= 10 && !mStateScrollTop) {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInUp)
                        .duration(150)
                        .playOn(iv_go_to_top);
                mStateScrollTop = true;

            } else if (dy > 0 && mStateScrollTop) {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutDown)
                        .duration(150)
                        .playOn(iv_go_to_top);
                mStateScrollTop = false;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your `onScrolled()`?

Comment: a condition for show a icon in items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
onScrolled() {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(!ready)
            return;
        else
            ready = false;
    }

    // your current onScroll body
}
```

And then you would launch a thread setting a `ready` variable to `true` in regular intervals. Something like this:

```
private void launchOnScrollThread() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // endless loop - maybe you would like to put some condition to end the loop
            for(;;) {
                ready = true;
                Thread.sleep(100);    // wait here for 100 milliseconds
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

This would ensure that your current code in `onScroll` will be executed at most every 100 milliseconds, which should speed it up. Sorry that it's kind of a pseudocode, hope it makes sense to you and will be helpful.